# Send object in window.refresh kendo grid mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

in javascript I want to send object in refresh for kendowindow

```
var object = {
            Number: "dfs",
            Id : 1,
            SelectedId:"dsf"
        }

var window = $("#Window").data("kendoWindow");
        window.refresh({
            url: url,
        data: {
            item: object
        }
    });
```

Model:

```
public class Weight
{
   public string Number { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

parameteres are null

```
public ActionResult Update(Weight item)
{
}
```

how i can send object to server correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.refresh({
            data: JSON.stringify(object),
            url: url,
        });
```

Comment: the same values of parameters

Comment: is it the JSON format you are sending?

                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"